# Помощь с карточкой товара

Tags: jquery

```css
.cart .img {
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    background-size: contain;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
}
.cart1 .img:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.cart1 .img:first-of-type {
    background: url(../images/es1-img1.jpg) center no-repeat;
}
.cart1 .img:nth-child(2) {
    background: url(../images/es1-img2.jpg) center no-repeat;
}
.cart1 .img:nth-child(3) {
    background: url(../images/es1-img3.jpg) center no-repeat;
}
.cart1 .img:nth-child(4) {
    background: url(../images/es1-img4.jpg) center no-repeat;
}
.cart1 .img:nth-child(5) {
    background: url(../images/es1-img5.jpg) center no-repeat;
}
.cart .big-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
 <div class="cart target cart1">
        <h2>Air Drive карбон</h2>
        <div class="close"></div>
        <div class="big-img"></div>
        <div class="cart-content">
            <div class="mini-gallery">
                <div class="img"></div>
                <div class="img"></div>
                <div class="img"></div>
                <div class="img"></div>
                <div class="img"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать что бы при клике на маленькую картинку она ставала вместо большой а большая стала на место миниатюры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первым делом нужно разбить задачу на подзадачи

1. Нужна функция, которая сделает background блока определенной картинкой (например через $.css() или через class, без разницы)
2. Нужна возможность определять, какая картинка сейчас у определенного блока (например через свойство $.css(), через класс или через атрибут блока, например `data-img="../images/es1-img5.jpg"`, как вариант)
3. Связать эти две возможности с кликом по блоку

Представим, что у нас есть эти функции:

1. GetImage(block) - возвращает изображение, которое установлено на блоке
2. SetImage(block, image) - устанавливает на блок изображение

Тогда определить логику клика становится очень просто:

```
$(function(){
    // Устанавливаем изображения при старте на каждый блок
    // Обратите внимание, что мы должны назначить картинки на все блоки,
    // то есть и на большой, и на маленький
    $(".cart1 .big-img, .cart1 .img").map(function(index, element){
        // Здесь может быть более сложный закон, разумеется,
        // но в примере они у вас нумеруются по порядку с единицы
        SetImage($(element), "../images/es1-img"+(index+1)+".jpg");
    });

    // Регистрируем клик на маленькую картинку
    // В этом случае должна происходить смена изображений
    $(".mini-gallery .img").click(function(){
        var small_image = GetImage($(this)); // Текущее изображение
        var big_image = GetImage($(".big-img"));
        if (small_image && big_image) {
            SetImage($(".big-img"), small_image);
            SetImage($(this), big_image);
        }
    });
});
```

Отлично, теперь у нас все работает - можете убедиться в этом с помощью вывода `console.log()`. Лучше это сделать сейчас, чтобы потом не мучится с логикой поведения

Теперь осталось определить функции `GetImage` и `SetImage`. Поскольку мы проектировали сверху вниз, мы знаем, что первый параметр у них обеих - это jQuery-объект блока div с картинкой, а изображение передается в виде строки URL

```
function GetImage(jqueryObjectBlock)
{
    // Здесь можно добавить более сложные проверки - на количество
    // элементов в наборе, на наличие атрибута, на наличие картинки
    // по URL в атрибуте. Оставляю это вам
    var image_url = $(jqueryObjectBlock).attr("image-url");
    return image_url ? image_url : "";
}

function SetImage(jqueryObjectBlock, image_url)
{
    // Тоже можно проверить переданный объект, переданный URL и так далее
    $(jqueryObjectBlock).attr("image-url", image_url);
    $(jqueryObjectBlock).css({"background-image":image_url});
}
```

На самом деле не важно, как именно реализованы эти две функции. Через класс, через прямой вызов `$.css()` или через атрибут блока. Главное - что они выполняют свою задачу. Я использовал атрибут для хранения строки и прямой вызов css для назначения URL изображения фона. Сделайте как вам больше нравится